# iOS Geolocation Not Updating

Tags: ios, xcode, geolocation, cllocation

Using iOS 8 and have NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription set.

Here is my code:

```
#import "GeoLocation.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation GeoLocation

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 5; //in meters
        // Check for iOS 8. Without this guard the code will crash with "unknown selector" on iOS 7.
        if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
            [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        }

        self.numberOfUpdates = 0;
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
    return self;
}

// Wait for location callbacks
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    NSLog(@"Location Updated: %@", [locations lastObject]);
}

- (float) getLatitude
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSLog(@"getLatitude: %f", self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude);
    appDelegate.gMyProfile.latitude = self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
    return self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
}

- (float) getLongitude
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSLog(@"getLongitude: %f", self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude);
    appDelegate.gMyProfile.longitude = self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
    return self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
}

- (float) getAltitude
{
    return self.locationManager.location.altitude;
}
```

When the user logs in, I instantiate a GeoLocation object, which turn on starts updating the location.

If I use
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 5; 
and walk around my house, didUpdateLocations won't fire.

However, if I get rid of 
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 5;
didUpdateLocations will fire every second.

Anything you guys see that I am not. I would love for this to update when the user moves 5 meters.

Comment: Do you have wifi turned on? Try turning it off.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a distance filter will most likely cause iOS to take the horizontalAccuracy into account.

Since you are inside you will be unlikely to get location with a horizontalAccuracy of 5 which is the best accuracy.

Without the distance filter you are probably just getting the same location or another location within the distance in horizontalAccuracy.

Generally you will only get an accuracy of 5m meters when you are outside in clear view of the satellites above you and not next to tall buildings that can reflect and obscure the signal.